# Azure Data Factory: LinkedService for AzureSql in failed state

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, cortana-intelligence

Azure Data Factory - getting started. (One similar question is unanswered.)

I am using the data factory to move data from Storage to a Azure SQL table.
I can create the linked servers OK but by the time I try to reference it in a DataSet that operation fails with an error pointing at the LinkedService:

> statusCode:BadRequest
>   serviceRequestId:f1e0d752-6d10-42db-b445-6c59d8eaf074
>   statusMessage:{"message":"Linked service AzureSqlLinkedService is not
>   ready. Current status: Failed. If AzureSqlLinkedService is in failed
>   state, you can investigate by getting the object and inspecting the
>   error message, then decide whether you need to update some of its
>   properties or recreate the object.","code":"LinkedServiceNotReady"}

I've tried to investigate the AzureSqlLinkedService which is now showing an error:

> ENTITY PROVISIONING FAILED: FAILED TO CONNECT TO LINKED SERVICE.
>   ERRORCODE:-2146232060.

This code appears in widely differing contexts so not great but the error message seems to be valid.  I have opened the firewall to allow connection to SQL Azure and see no errors about credentials or connectivity.

I tried to get more from PowerShell but no joy: "ProvisioningState : Failed" is all it adds.

Pointers please?

Answer (score 1):

this error indicates that ADF is unable to connect to the Azure SQL database you are defining as a LinkedService.  Have you enabled "Allow access to Azure services" setting on the Azure SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"connectionString": "Server=tcp:.database.windows.net,1433;Database=;User ID=;Password=;Integrated Security=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30"
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, double check your connection string. It is definitely and issue reaching to or getting authenticated by the SQL Azure server.